# how this step was turned into that step when I calcuate the derivative of cost function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was trying to figure it out how the calculate the  derivative of cost function  ,I have no idea with this,from this formula we gonna calculate the derivative

$J\left(\theta \right)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum _{i=1}^m\left(y^{\left(i\right)}\log _{h\theta }\left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)+\left(1-y^{\left(^i\right)}\right)\log _{ }\left(1-h\theta ^{ }\left(X^{\left(i\right)}\right)\right)\right)\:$

then it turned to be

$\frac{dJ\left(\theta \right)}{d\theta j}=\frac{1}{m}\sum _{n=1}^m\:\left(y^{\left(i\right)}\frac{1}{h\theta x^{\left(i\right)}}\frac{dh\theta \left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)}{d\theta }-\left(1-y^{\left(i\right)}\right)\frac{1}{1-h\theta \left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)}\frac{dh\theta \left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)}{d\theta }\right)$

I totally have no idea how $\log \:_{h\theta \:}\left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)$ truned to be  $\frac{dh\theta \left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)}{d\theta }$ and

$\log \:_{\:}\left(1-h\theta \:^{\:}\left(X^{\left(i\right)}\right)\right)$ truned to be $\frac{1}{1-h\theta \:\left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)}\frac{dh\theta \:\left(x^{\left(i\right)}\right)}{d\theta \:}$

any idea?much apperciated